# what order for rails require gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

For my project, I use `Rubocop` to check the code style, the `Rubocop` require gems should be alphabetically sorted within groups. But when I changed the order, the CI failed, the error as below:

> bundle exec rake assets:precompile rake aborted! NameError:
>   uninitialized constant Kaminari::Helpers::Paginator

I have to put the `kaminari-mongoid` and `kaminari-actionview` after `mongoid`, then the CI will pass:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.1.5'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid', '~> 1.0.1'  # rubocop:disable Bundler/OrderedGems
gem 'kaminari-actionview', '~> 1.0.1' # rubocop:disable Bundler/OrderedGems
```

Rails how to decide the required order?

Comment: I fail to see how moving `mongoid` has anything to do with `kaminari` page rendering? I think your real issue is that you are missing `kaminari-core` some how

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty lines and/or comments to group the gems, and RuboCop won't bug you about it:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.1.5'

# Needs to come after mongoid
gem 'kaminari-mongoid', '~> 1.0.1'

# Needs to come after kaminari-mongoid
gem 'kaminari-actionview', '~> 1.0.1'
```